# The Code is not executing and telling its an infinite loop. Can anyone explain why?

Tags: java

The Code is not executing and telling its an infinite loop. Can anyone explain why? Even if it is not infinite loop why is it not generating result?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    static String feeOrUpfront(int n, int k, int x, int d, int[] p) {
        // Complete this function
        int temp;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i: p) {
            if (((p[i] / 100) * x) < k)
                temp = k;
            else temp = ((p[i] / 100) * x);
            sum += temp;
        }
        if (sum > d)
            return ("Fee"); //condition checking
        else
            return ("Upfront");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int q = in .nextInt();
        for (int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++) {
            int n = in .nextInt();
            int k = in .nextInt();
            int x = in .nextInt();
            int d = in .nextInt();
            int[] p = new int[n];
            for (int p_i = 0; p_i < n; p_i++) {
                p[p_i] = in .nextInt();
            }
            String result = feeOrUpfront(n, k, x, d, p); //getting result
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking people for help, take the time to format and indent your code consistently and readably. (It's a good idea when not asking for help, too.) **Edit:** I've done it for you on this occasion.

Comment: By far the best way to figure this out is by *debugging*. Use the debugger built into your IDE to step through the code statement by statement, examine variables at various times, etc. That will show you what's going on. Using a debugger is **not** an advanced skill, it's a basic thing that every beginner should learn immediately after (or even during) writing "Hello, world."

Comment: Show what you have entered for `n`, `k`, `x` and `d` from the command line.   A possible reason why it doesn't print anything is because you entered 0 for n.

Comment: (As you appear to be a beginner, can I also **strongly** recommend always using `{}` on branches, even single-statement branches.)

Comment: What makes you think it's in an infinite loop?

Comment: To make your code [mcve] , remove `Scanner` and initialize `n, k, x, d, p`  with values that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

try this code for

> feeOrUpfront()

```
   static String feeOrUpfront(int n, int k, int x, int d, int[] p) {
    // Complete this function

int temp;int sum=0;
        for (int i:p){
            if(((i/100)*x)<k)
                temp=k;
            else temp=((i/100)*x);
            sum+=temp;
        }
        if(sum>d) return("Fee");//condition checking
        else return("Upfront");
}
```